# Edit lines in text file with python

Tags: python-2.7, text-files

I am trying to create a list of files including their full addresses. They're stored on the Grid File Access Library from CERN which means I access them using `gfal-ls`, and as far as I know `gfal-find` doesn't exist.

My current python 2.7 code is:

```
lscommand = "gfal-ls root://address/moreaddress/MyFiles | head -20 > MyListName.txt"
os.system(lsCommand)
```

which creates `MyListName.txt` as so:

```
file1.root
file2.root
...
file20.root
```

What I now want to be able to do is to open this list and add `root://address/moreaddress/MyFiles/` before each filename.

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution looks like this:

```
lscommand = "gfal-ls root://address/moreaddress/MyFiles | head -20 > MyListName.txt"

FileList = commands.getstatusoutput(lsCommand)[1]
FileList=FileList.split('\n')

with open(ListFileName,"w") as fulllist: 
    for MyFile in FileList:
        fulllist.write("directoryname/"+MyFile+"\n")
```